# How to scroll through dates on a table and pass the date to a variable?

Tags: mysql

We have a 'Day' table in our DB that determines the dates school is in session. If the Attendance column has a value of one, then it's a school day. For example, these are the days in Jan when school is in session (I've only listed out one calendarID, which represents one school.

```
date    attendance  calendarID
1/3/2018    1       2062
1/4/2018    1       2062
1/5/2018    1       2062
1/8/2018    1       2062
1/9/2018    1       2062
1/10/2018   1       2062
1/11/2018   1       2062
1/12/2018   1       2062
1/16/2018   1       2062
1/18/2018   1       2062
1/19/2018   1       2062
1/22/2018   1       2062
1/24/2018   1       2062
1/25/2018   1       2062
1/26/2018   1       2062
1/29/2018   1       2062
1/30/2018   1       2062
1/31/2018   1       2062
```

Our enrollment table has the student ID, the date the student started and the date the student ended, the calendarID, as well as much other information. In order to determine how many students were enrolled on each school day in session - I can get the correct count by 'hard-coding' the date I want into the following query:

```
    select '1/3/2018' as Date
    , count(personID) as StudentCount
    , calendarID as SchoolNo
    from enrollment e
    where e.calendarID in (2062, 2063, 2064, 2065, 2066)
    and e.startDate <= '1/3/2018'
    and (e.endDate is null or e.endDate >= '1/3/2018')
    group by calendarID
```

That gives the following correct output:

```
ReportDate  StudentCount    SchoolNo
1/3/2018    468             2062
1/3/2018    260             2063
1/3/2018    456             2064
1/3/2018    249             2065
1/3/2018    290             2066
```

What I would like to be able to do is read through the 'Day' table to pick up the first date and replace the hard-coded dates with a variable and continue reading through the table so all dates are listed with the student counts for each school.

I got close with the following query, but the numbers are incorrect because I'm using the first date of the school year (7/1/2017) and it needs to pass the date read from the 'Day' table to use in looking at the start and end dates in the enrollment table.

```
select convert(date, d.date) as ReportDate
, CAST(count(e.personID)as decimal(10,2)) as StudentCount
, e.calendarID as SchoolNo
from enrollment e
left join [Day] d on d.calendarID = e.CalendarID and d.attendance = 1 and d.date between '8/30/2017' and getDate()
Where e.calendarID in (2062, 2063, 2064, 2065, 2066)
    and e.startDate between '7/1/2017' and d.date 
    and (e.endDate is null or e.endDate <= d.date)
    and d.date is not null
group by d.date
, e.calendarID
```

The result gives me a count of students for each calendarID for each date in the school year. I am culling out just the date of 1/3/2018 to show here. But again, the numbers are incorrect.

```
ReportDate  StudentCount    SchoolNo
1/3/2018    486             2062
1/3/2018    264             2063
1/3/2018    459             2064
1/3/2018    253             2065
1/3/2018    288             2066
```

Comment: Step one: store dates as dates. Fix that. Then get back to us.

Comment: The dates are stored as dates, I only did the above to show an example.

Comment: OK. Fix the above example. Then see: [Why should I provide an MCVE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Comment: Thank you for looking at this. I'll figure it out on my own as I took extra time to build the 'fake' query so an MCVE would know what I'm trying to get to. The second query is the real query and uses the dates correctly. I don't know how to fix a 'fake' query. Again, I apologize I wasted you time.

Comment: Great. Please delete the question.

Comment: If I knew how to I would. But apparently I'm pretty stupid.